# 301 Redirects with dynamic URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite my .htaccess file to redirect old dynamic URLS to new ones.

I have tried these so far but they are not working as expected. The second rule seems to redirect to the first one.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /product.php?l=old-product-name1 http://www.mydomain.com/product.php?l=new-product-name1
Redirect 301 /product.php?l=old-product-name2 http://www.mydomain.com/product.php?l=new-product-name2
```

Can anyone help me redirect these properly?

Comment: can you give me an example with URLs. old url example and new url example.

Comment: Old URL: www.mydomain.com/product.php?l=Non_Slip_Footwear

New URL: www.mydomain.com/product.php?l=Safety_Shoes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =l=old-product-name1
    RewriteRule ^product.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/product.php?l=new-product-name1 [R=301]
```